# How to ignore/exclude dot files, dot folder in phpDocumentor 3?

Tags: php, phpdoc

I have folders and files like this.

```
index.php
System
  aa.php
.backup
  anything-in-dot-backup.php
.ignoreme.php
```

I would like to ignore/exclude those dot folders and dot files in phpDocumentor 3 but this config xml seems to not working.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<phpdocumentor
        configVersion="3"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="https://www.phpdoc.org"
>
    <title><![CDATA[My title]]></title>
    <paths>
        <cache>.phpdoc/cache</cache>
        <output>.apidoc</output>
    </paths>
    <version number="latest">
        <api>
            <ignore hidden="false">
                <path>.backup/**/*</path>
                <path>\.backup/**/*</path>
                <path>\\.backup/**/*</path>
                <path>\\\.backup/**/*</path>
                <path>.*.php</path>
                <path>Test*/**/*</path>
            </ignore>
        </api>
    </version>
</phpdocumentor>
```

How to ignore dot folders and dot files in phpDocumentor 3?